# How can i format a number string using jQuery Number Plugin using "," as decimal delimiter

Tags: jquery, string-formatting

I use [jQuery Number Plugin](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/) to format my percentage values to my desired format on a website. However, when i try to format the value  `0.5` to look like `0,50` the value becomes `5,00`.

The error seems to appear when I set the decimal delimiter to something other than `.`. Why is this?

Se fiddle for example

http://jsfiddle.net/9C828/2/

Comment: http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format-redux/196/

http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/issues/43

I switched to use [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) which seems to work good for my cause!